# Perforce adding a folder to depot

Tags: perforce

I am new to Perforce. Could you add a new folder under the branch in the depot? I also tried to add one in my workplace but how could I get it to the depot? Do I have to do a merge/integrate or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware that Perforce doesn't know about folders, any files.  Hence in Dave's answer you need to have a placeholder file in the new folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From your local workspace, create your folder and a file you want to go inside it.  Then either mark it as add from the visual client, or go into the folder from the command line, and type...

```
p4 add ./new_folder/new_file_name.ext
```

When you submit, the new file and folder will be in your repository.  This assumes that `new_folder` is a subfolder of your existing workspace.  Please let me know if it isn't and I'll update my answer.

Above command will add files under default changelist. And later if you want to see the if files are really added in default changelist

```
p4 opened
```

And for the submission of opened files, under the default changelist, to depot

```
p4 submit
```

Answer (score 29):

**p4 add** doesn't support recursive add .

Here's a unix shell work-around to run from within the root folder you want to add:

```
find . -type f -print | p4 -x - add
```

Comment: Starting with the 2015.1 release (see release note 900158), `p4 add` supports the `...` syntax, and will perform recursive add.

Answer (score 18):

Use command

```
p4 add directory_to_be_added/...
```

This will recursively add all contents starting drom "directory_to_be_added"

Answer (score 17):

If your server version is 2012.1 or later, you can use the [reconcile](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_reconcile.html) command to do this, with full wildcard support:

```
p4 reconcile //depot/path/to/folder/...
```

Answer (score 3):

To add files from a directory in perforce

> `p4 reconcile -f -c [changeList] -a <dir_path_to add>`

Comment: can't add files that are not yet on the depot this way.

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation that I need to add entire folder with files having wildcard name, so had to do it through command line using -f (force), I used "dir /b /s /a-d | p4 -x - add -f"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using p4v to add a folder recursively, you need to click on:

`"Connection" -> "Edit Current Workspace"`

then *manually* add the mapping of the new folder to your depot.

Then go to your "Workspace" view and right click on the root folder, click "Mark for Add" and comment. All the files under it should show up in the new pending change list.